# Javascript disable input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two input fields one is for a phone number another is for an email. I would like to disable one field based on the user selection. Should a user click and enter input in either field, it would disable the other and vice versa.

I have written code but it seems to only disable the email field upon entering in numbers in the phone field. Removing the numbers in the phone field removes the disabled from the email input field.

IN MY HTML

```
 <input type="number" name="number" placeholder="hone" class="cellphone" data-cp-visibility="new-user" id="phone">

 <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="enter email" class="email" data-cp-visibility="new-user" id="email">
```

IN JAVASCRIPT

```
 $('#phone').live('blur',function(){ 
     if(document.getElementById('phone').value > 1) {
        $('#email').attr('disabled', true);
      } else {
       $('#email').attr('disabled', false);
  }
 });

$('#email').live('blur',function(){ 
   if(document.getElementById('email').value > 1) {
    $('#phone').attr('disabled', true);
     } else {
       $('#phone').attr('disabled', false);
   }
});
```

Ultimately I what I am trying to accomplish is that a user can click in either field and then enter input, upon doing so, the other field is disabled. Should they choose to remove the text they entered, it would remove the disabled feature and then they could choose the opposite input field.

I am not sure why it only works for one field and not the other or why if you enter in 333-333-3333 in the phone field it breaks the disabled, but 33333333 works fine.

Any ideas or insight as to what I may be missing?

Comment: Wrong method, you should be using `prop`, not `attr` !

Comment: Also, an email is probably not *"more than 1"*, seems like you want to check if the trimmed value equals `""` (empty string)

Comment: Finally, `live()` was deprecated and removed several years ago

Comment: You're also using a mix a javascript and jquery.  I don't see a reason to write code that complicates what your trying to do by doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to fix the dash issue you are having with the phone input, you can try changing it to:

```
<input type="text" required="" pattern="\d{3}[\-]\d{3}[\-]\d{4}" name="phone" id="phone"  data-cp-visibility="new-user" placeholder="123-345-5678">
```

and here is another version of the js:

```
var $phone = $('#phone'),
    $email = $('#email');

$phone.on('keyup change', function() {

   $email.prop('disabled', $(this).val() ? true : false );

});

$email.on('keyup change', function() {

    $phone.prop('disabled', $(this).val() ? true : false );

});
```

Comment: Good, but I can cut out the entire value using only my mouse...  you should include the `change` event.

Answer (score 0):

You may use jQuery `on` instead of `live`. live is  deprecated as of jQuery 1.7.
You can also look for the `keyup`/`keydown` event on the input element.

```
$(function(){

   $('#phone').on('keyup',function(){ 

      if($(this).val()!=="") 
      {
        $('#email').prop('disabled', true);
      }
      else {
        $('#email').attr('disabled', false);
      }
   });

   $('#email').on('keyup',function(){ 

      if($(this).val()!=="") 
      { 
         $('#phone').prop('disabled', true);
      }
      else {
          $('#phone').prop('disabled', false);
      }
  });      

});
```

[Here](http://jsbin.com/seliha/edit?html,js,console,output) is a working sample.

Comment: Good, but I can cut out the entire value using only my mouse...  you should include the `change` event.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `.on('input', ...)` to listen for changes, this makes it so even if you use the increment/decrement buttons (or other forms of input) you'll trigger the event-handler. Then use `.attr('disabled', boolean)` to control enable/disabled state, see example below:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#phone').on('input', function() {
    $('#email').attr('disabled', $(this).val() !== "");
  });
  $('#email').on('input', function() {
    $('#phone').attr('disabled', $(this).val() !== "");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" placeholder="phone" id="phone">
<input type="email" placeholder="enter email" id="email">
```